# Bash "newest directory" working differently from CL vs from Script

Tags: bash

I've been using `cd  "$(\ls -1dt ./*/ | head -n 1)"` in some scripts to get into a new directory after creating it. I decided to put an alias in my `bash_profile`:

```
alias newest="cd $(\ls -1dt ./*/ | head -n 1)"
```

But when I run `newest` from the command line, it goes to a different directory, which happens to be the first one alphabetically though I don't know if that's why it's choosing that directory.

Pasting `cd  "$(\ls -1dt ./*/ | head -n 1)"` directly into the command line works correctly. What's going on here?

Comment: Keep in mind that the `alias` command is parsed the same way every other command is, so double-quoted strings in its arguments have command substitutions executed *before* `alias` is invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Don't* use `ls -t` in scripts at all -- see [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) on why it's unreliable, and [BashFAQ #3](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) on what to do instead. But ignoring that, the smallest fix for the immediate, narrow issue is to use a function:

```
newest() { cd "$(command ls -1dt ./*/ | head -n 1)"; }
```

Your alias was having the command substitution run *at time of definition*, not on invocation. If you *really* want it to still be an alias, you could use single quotes on the outside to prevent that command substitution from happening early:

```
alias newest='cd "$(\ls -1dt ./*/ | head -n 1)"'
```

---

What would a reliable, best-practice approach look like? Perhaps:

```
cdNewest() {
   local latest='' candidate
   set -- */
   [[ -d $1 ]] || return  # handle case where no directories exist so glob did not expand
   latest=$1; shift
   for candidate; do
     [[ $candidate -nt $latest ]] && latest=$candidate
   done
   cd -- "$latest"
}
```

...which, instead of running two external commands (`ls` and `head`), runs none at all (and also avoids the need for command substitutions and pipelines, both of which are quite high-overhead, altogether).